# define Class from imported file

Tags: javascript, class, declaration, eslint

I'm trying to use "cropperjs" from fengyuanche, and ESLint reports an undefined Class. What is the right way to declare it ? Thank you.

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do :

```
define( ["./cropperjs/dist/cropper"], () => { 

    function initCropper($options) {

            // ESlint : "Cropper" is undefined
            const cropper = new Cropper (...)
            return cropper;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it into the `define` callback:

```
define( ["./cropperjs/dist/cropper"], (Cropper) => { 

    function initCropper($options) {

            // ESlint : "Cropper" is undefined
            const cropper = new Cropper (...)
            return cropper;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: No worries @BertrandEngogram. Please accept my answer when you get a chance :)

Comment: Also, you may find it useful to read more about "AMD" (asynchronous module definition) to find out more about how it works. https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD